# Python; How to turn each line of a text file into a separate string element in a list:

Tags: python, list

I am very new to python. What I would like to do is to enter a list of items separated by line, like so:

> **item number one**
>
> **item number two**
>
> **item number three**

and have them added to a list like:

> **['item number one', 'item number two', 'item number three']**

Thanks!

Comment: How will you end the list?

Comment: This is a little broad. What is your input? A file or standard in?

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming, from the title of your post, that you've been given a text file, which I'll call `file.txt`.

```
with open('file.txt') as rd:
    items = rd.readlines()
```

`readlines()` automatically breaks up the file by newspace characters and returns the contents of a file as a list of strings, one string for each line.  To get rid of the newlines, use the `strip()` function.  For example, you can replace `items=rd.readlines()` with `items = [x.strip() for x in rd.readlines()]`.

Comment: Note that this keeps the newline characters at the ends of the strings.

Comment: very true... I added a suggestion to use `items = [x.strip() for x in rd.readlines()]` to get rid of them.

Answer (score 1):

```
items = []

while True: 
    item = raw_input()
    if not item: #if you want to end just hit enter without typing anything
        break
    items.append(item)

print items
```

Comment: Or if felt like it: `items = list(iter(raw_input, ''))`

Comment: @JonClements Of course, but he said that he is a beginner.